# "<>" key not working on Lite Linux (Ubuntu). Laptop HP Pavilion 11-u001ns

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, key-bindings, autokey

Been trying to figure out how to make this key work, but it just acts as a control key. I'm currently using a 105-key Spanish (Windows) layout, where the "<>" key is between Alt gr and the left arrow. xbindkeys key code: m:0x14 + c:105

[This is the laptop's layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv0sL.png)

Tried AutoKey with the following code:

```
# AutoKey script to create a "<>" key
output = "<>"

if event.keycode == 105 and event.get_modifier_state("Shift_L"):
    keyboard.send_keys(">")
elif event.keycode == 105:
    keyboard.send_keys("<")
```

but it crashed when I was setting the hotkeys.

Also tried editing the keyboard configuration file with no results, as I don't know what to modify.